# What's more stronger in meaning of "not interesting","dull" or "boring"?

Tags: word-difference

In everyday spoken language, what's more stronger in meaning of "not interesting", is it "**dull**" or "**boring**"?

According to Oxford dictionary:

[**dull**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dull): Lacking interest or excitement.

[**boring**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/boring): Not interesting; tedious.

N.b. can I say about a show, person, lecture, even, teacher etc, that they are **dull**?

Based on that, they seem to be the same or synonyms (I don't really remember when I heard dull in such context. What I used to hear is the dull as a synonym of sharp.)

Comment: The use of [double comparatives](https://www.thoughtco.com/double-comparatives-1210274) e.g. "more stronger" is considered non-standard in English.

Comment: I think you were looking for the expression "more derogatory" or "Which word/term has *more negative* connotations?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "dull" and "boring" have similar levels of intensity.

In American English, the more common and typical word is "boring".

The problem with saying a teacher is dull, is that it doesn't clearly indicate "not interesting".  There is another definition of dull: "mentally slow; lacking brightness of mind; somewhat stupid; obtuse."